# importando dados Xml para banco Mysql - Só grava o ÚLTIMO registro

Tags: php, mysql, xml, foreach, sql-insert

Nesse codigo acontece a leitura de todos os registros do XML mas no banco Mysql só se grava o ultimo bloco de registro do XML. 
Eu sei que a leitura de cada registro sobre-escreve o anterior mas o estranho é que dei um ECHO e comprovei que o loop do foreach traz todos os registros do xml mas na hora de gravar no banco só grava o último registro.
Onde está o problema nessa lógica?

Olá Mauro Alexandre, obrigado por responder:
codigo completo aqui:

```
 <?php
$servername = "xxxxx";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$affectedRow = 0;
$xml = simplexml_load_file("americana.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach ($xml->return as $registro) :
echo $registro->campaignID."<br/>";
echo $registro->categoryID."<br/>";

$sql = "INSERT INTO rakupom_cupom_temp (id_cupom, campaignID, categoryID, categoryName, linkID, linkName, mid, nid, imgURL, cupom_preco, cupom_codigo, cupom_desconto,clickURL, startDate, endDate,  landURL, showURL,textDisplay, clickTNNT,  cupom_bit, cupom_status)
VALUES (NULL, '".$registro->campaignID."', '".$registro->categoryID."', '".$registro->categoryName."', '".$registro->linkID."', '".$registro->linkName."', '".$registro->mid."', '".$registro->nid."', '$imgURL', '$cupom_preco', '$cupom_codigo', '$cupom_desconto', '".$registro->clickURL."', '".$registro->startDate."', '".$registro->endDate."', '".$registro->landURL."', '".$registro->showURL."', '".$registro->textDisplay."', '$clickTNNT', '$cupom_bit', '$cupom_status')";

endforeach; // FIM DO FOREACH

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

ARQUIVO XML

```
 <getTextLinksResponse xmlns:ns1="http://endpoint.linkservice.linkshare.com/">
  <return>
    <campaignID>0</campaignID>
    <categoryID>200610822</categoryID>
    <categoryName>CUPOM</categoryName>
    <linkID>5081</linkID>
    <linkName>Cupom de 10% OFF em seleção de malas e acessórios (Código: MOCHILA10) - Válido para produtos vendidos e entregues por My Store.</linkName>
    <mid>42758</mid>
    <nid>8</nid>
    <clickURL>http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=iE1EFPFJmpE&amp;offerid=575927.5081&amp;type=3</clickURL>
    <endDate>Aug 11, 2018</endDate>
    <landURL>https://www.americanas.com.br/categoria/malas-e-acessorios/f/loja-My%20Store</landURL>
    <showURL>http://ad.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/show?id=iE1EFPFJmpE&amp;bids=575927.5081&amp;type=3</showURL>
    <startDate>Jul 23, 2018</startDate>
    <textDisplay>Cupom de 10% OFF em seleção de malas e acessórios (Código: MOCHILA10) - Válido para produtos vendidos e entregues por My Store.</textDisplay>
  </return>
  <return>
    <campaignID>0</campaignID>
    <categoryID>200610822</categoryID>
    <categoryName>CUPOM</categoryName>
    <linkID>5064</linkID>
    <linkName>Cupom de 10% de desconto em Drones (Código: DRONE10) - Válido para produtos vendidos por My Store.</linkName>
    <mid>42758</mid>
    <nid>8</nid>
    <clickURL>http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=iE1EFPFJmpE&amp;offerid=575927.5064&amp;type=3</clickURL>
    <endDate>Aug 12, 2018</endDate>
    <landURL>https://www.americanas.com.br/categoria/cameras-e-filmadoras/f/tag-tag-cinefoto-mystoredji</landURL>
    <showURL>http://ad.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/show?id=iE1EFPFJmpE&amp;bids=575927.5064&amp;type=3</showURL>
    <startDate>Jul 18, 2018</startDate>
    <textDisplay>Cupom de 10% de desconto em Drones (Código: DRONE10) - Válido para produtos vendidos por My Store.</textDisplay>
  </return>
</getTextLinksResponse>
```

PHP

Comment: Mostre o código completo, você está usando PDO ou Mysqli? Mostra a parte da inserção

Comment: Oi Mauro, obrigado por responder. Eu coloquei o codigo completo na minha pergunta...

Comment: Será que eu consegui explicar direito minha dúvida? - o foreach traz todos os loops do arquivo XML (comprovei isso ao dar um ECHO em dois registros) mas no INSERT na tabela do mysql só se grava o ultimo bloco de registros do arquivo xml...

Comment: Eu já respondi a pergunta, pode comentar diretamente lá na resposta.

Answer (score 1):

O problema está na lógica da aplicação.

A sua variável `$sql` está sobrescrevendo o valor anterior dentro do laço de repetição; o valor armazenado na variável será o último.

Para resolver esse problema, basta colocar o seguinte trecho de código dentro do `foreach`, após a query.

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

A cada iteração ele vai armazenar seus valores.

Comment: RESOLVIDO!! É por isso que confio tanto nessa comunidade! Só profissionais de alta qualidade! Muito obrigado Mauro Alexandre! Resolveu um GRANDE GRANDE problema no meu sistema. um Ótimo dia para todos!

Comment: @JoaoMarceloFarias fico feliz em ter ajudado, você pode retribuir a comunidade marcando a resposta como aceita, para ajudar quem venha a ter a mesma dúvida.